# Does waiting for bread to rise before baking change its nutrient composition?

Tags: bread, nutrient-composition, rising

Does waiting for bread to rise before baking change the amount of standard macro- or micronutrients present? I imagine that baking would evaporate any alcohols produced by the yeast fermentation. So the final product would simply have less sugar. Is this correct? Or is there more to it?

Comment: Hi, nutrition is usually off topic here. We do allow a very narrowly defined part of it, which is concerned with the numerical measurement of concrete nutrients present in food, and I think your question can be seen as falling within this exception. But I had to edit it because we cannot talk about any broad nutritional properties here, just about things like "x percent less sugar" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

No difference in nutritional properties. It is just the difference between bread and hardtack. The "fermentation" isn't to make ethanol, but rather to release carbon dioxide in the bread which creates "air" bubbles making the product soft.